# Cannot update Job.ttlSecondsAfterFinished in a mutating webhook

Tags: kubernetes

I'm developing a mutating webhook for Kubernetes with the following functionality:

- watch `Job` status (jobs are spawned by `CronJob`)
- if job was successful, add `ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 0` to it (so it can be garbage collected)
- if job failed, leave it as is

Problem is, API server only seems to apply the patch I return as part of `AdmissionReview.response.patch` **partially**:

patch I return:

```
[
{"op": "add", "path": "/metadata/labels/testlabel", "value": "a"},
{"op": "add", "path": "/spec", "value": {"ttlSecondsAfterFinished": 0}}
]
```

(I also tried formulating it as `{"op": "add", "path": "/spec/ttlSecondsAfterFinished", "value": 0}` but the result was the same)

and after the webhook return it, I check the affected `Job` object and notice:

- label `testlabel: a` **is** present
- `ttlSecondsAfterFinished` **is not** present

Curiously, if I then `kubectl edit` the object and do a non-related change (say, add another label), job is immediately removed (presumably because ttl is now set?)

I'm using Kubernetes v1.24.13; happy to attach whatever might helps in debugging

Comment: why don't you directly call the delete API for the jobs that have completed since you are already watching them